# Java Program to find image in .java or .jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

I have a project with around 50 java classes/files (this 50 files includes both JSP and Java files). In this files I have written code to display abc.jpg image on my JSP pages. Now I want to write a java program which will replace all the abc.jpg images by xyz.jpg image in my project. I have no clue how I can do this. Also suggest if there is any free tool available to do the same.

Comment: Do you want to update the name of images in explorer folder or in the java and jsp files?

Comment: In java and jsp files

Comment: open all files in notepad++, search "abc.jpg" and replace "xyz.jpg", save all

Comment: Hi Christoph, Thanks for the suggestion. But we are doing the same manually but now we want to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, will be done using following steps. Please note that you can find information about each step in StackOverflow itself in different posts:

```
1. Create a traversal policy for a directory in which all files are present, to get path of all .java and .jsp files.  
2. Read all files one-by-one and write its content to another temporary file line by line.  
3. While reading individual line, check whether it contains the name of .jpg file whose name you want to update. If yes the replace the name with new name and write the current updated line in temporary file.  
4. Once the file reading is completed, delete the original file and rename the temporary file to original one.  
5. Now you will have a same file with updated names of .jpg files.  
6. Repeat the steps from 2-5 until all files are read and write.
```

Hope this will help. And yes you have to search these methods in SO itself. :-)

Comment: Hi Aman let me try this and get back. Just one dough here. I have written java programs to .txt file. Will the same program for for reading .java or .jsp file? ..Initially i was planning of converting all the java files to txt and then search for the same. But let me try your solution.

Comment: No pratham it will work for .java and .jsp file also. You do not need to convert them to .txt file.

Comment: If you do not want to do this programmatically , then I tell you an easiest solution. Just open your project in Eclipse and use Eclipse's search and replace feature. It is same as search and replace data from a text file in notepad. Just difference is that it will search in entire project and replace it. Easiest solution if thats your only need. :-P